# StateHasChanged/this.StateHasChanged doesn't seem to have effect on Blazor Component

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, mudblazor

I am working on a .net5 Blazor WebApp using the MudBlazor library.
I'm trying to create a nav menu that displays certain categories and category pages. But as there is the possibility to add new categories, or add new category pages I need to refresh my component when the info has changed. When calling the function in `OnInitializedAsync()` this has no problem with rendering the nav menu as it's supposed to. But when calling it again after updating any of the information that it should render, this function no longer seems to do what it's supposed to do, which is re-rendering the component. Now, the easiest solution could be that I can simply refresh the whole page. But this isn't what I want as there is other logic that needs to keep running without being interfered with by the reload of the page. My .razor file looks like the following:

```cs
@inject CategoryService categoryService
@inject CategoryPageService categoryPageService

@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="px-4" Style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; text-align:center">Categories</MudText>
<MudDivider />
<MudNavMenu Style="color:white">
@foreach (Category category in NavCategories)
{
    @if(NavCategoryPages.Count > 0)
    {
        @foreach(CategoryPage categoryPage in NavCategoryPages)
        {
            @if(categoryPage.CategoryId == category.Id)
            {
                <MudNavGroup Title=@category.Name>
                    @foreach(CategoryPage categoryPage1 in NavCategoryPages.Where(c => c.CategoryId == category.Id))
                    {
                        <MudNavLink>@categoryPage1.PageName</MudNavLink>
                    }
                </MudNavGroup>
            }
            else
            {
                <MudNavLink>@category.Name</MudNavLink> 
            }
        }
    }
}
</MudNavMenu>

@code
{
    private List<Category> NavCategories = new List<Category>();
    private List<CategoryPage> NavCategoryPages = new List<CategoryPage>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetCategoriesNav(); //Function that should grab the new information from the database
    }

    public async Task GetCategoriesNav()
    {
        NavCategories = await categoryService.GetCategories();
        NavCategoryPages = await categoryPageService.GetCategoryPages();
        //This delay is to have enough time to view if the StateHasChanged has any effect on first call.
        await Task.Delay(5000);

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

I've double-checked all the values which they have to display and they show up accordingly in the debug. If you need any extra information don't hesitate to ask.

The first call is being made in:

- CategorySelector.razor

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetCategoriesNav();
    }
```

This call renders the NavMenu as it's supposed to. After that, the only time it's being called somewhere else is when I edit/add a category. This is done in:

- CategoryAdministration

```cs
//These 2 functions are called via a button.
async Task AddCategory()
    {
        Category thisCategory = new();

        var param = new DialogParameters { ["category"] = thisCategory };

        IDialogReference dialog = DialogService.Show<CategoryDialog>("Add Category", param);

        DialogResult result = await dialog.Result;
        if(!result.Cancelled)
        {
            GetCategories();
            //if a category has succesfully been added, it calls the same method which also gets called in the "OnInitializedAsync()"
            await GetCategoriesNav();
        }
    }


    async Task EditCategory(Category category)
    {
        category = await categoryService.EditCategory(category);

        var param = new DialogParameters { ["category"] = category };

        var dialog = DialogService.Show<CategoryDialog>("Edit Category", param);

        DialogResult result = await dialog.Result;
        if (!result.Cancelled)
        {
            GetCategories();
//if a category has succesfully been edited, it calls the same method which also gets called in the "OnInitializedAsync()"
            await GetCategoriesNav();
        }
    }
```

This here is the only external place this is being called, but CategoryAdministration inherits from Category selector.

Comment: Try `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` this is sometimes required in async to get the StateHasChanged() issued on the UI thread.

Comment: Show us how this is happening : Quote : "But when calling it again after updating any of the information that it should render"

Comment: @MisterMagoo Initially it gets called in
```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetCategoriesNav();
    }
```
When applying changes, I call this function from somewhere else

Comment: ```cs
 async Task EditCategory(Category category)
    {
        category = await categoryService.EditCategory(category);

        var param = new DialogParameters { ["category"] = category };

        var dialog = DialogService.Show<CategoryDialog>("Edit Category", param);

        DialogResult result = await dialog.Result;
        if (!result.Cancelled)
        {
            GetCategories();
            await GetCategoriesNav();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are not able to edit your question? If you can, please do that with the new information. Is that EditCategory method part of this component or elsewhere? What calls that method?

Comment: @MisterMagoo Sorry I got caught up with lunch, anyway. I have `CategorySelector.razor` which is the full script I posted in the question. This script holds the function which should update the list and re-render accordingly with `StateHasChanged()`. The second call is made externally from a script called `CategoryAdministration.razor` which waits for the database to be updated and saved before calling `GetCategoriesNav()` again and try to re-render the component.

Comment: @BrianParker this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Your descriptions are not specific enough and your diagram is behind a login. If you cannot edit your question, please find another place to share the exact code that is calling GetCategoriesNav() "again" making it clear which code file each call is in.

Comment: We can't see how/where you call AddCategory() but do avoid `async void`.

Comment: Add and Delete are called via a button.

Comment: https://cacoo.com/diagrams/M4SfP2nbgLt1n7ki/458A1

Comment: @Rowin please show that buttons markup/source

Comment: @abberdeen                `<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Secondary" OnClick="() => AddCategory()">Add Category</MudButton>
`

Comment: If you can simplify your code and reproduce your problem in a snippet on https://try.mudblazor.com then we could directly find a working solution instead of guessing what is the problem with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a management page CategoryAdmin.razor with buttons that open Dialogs with an editor - Category Dialog.

Within that page you have a component - I assume called `NavCategoriesComponent` - that displays the NavCategories.

You click on one of your buttons and edit/add a category, but on exit from the dialog the list in the NavCategories component doesn't update.

You also have a `CategoryService` that I'm assuming gets the list of categories.

In `NavCategoriesComponent` you code looks like this:

```
private List<Category> NavCategories = new List<Category>();
private List<CategoryPage> NavCategoryPages = new List<CategoryPage>();

//OnInit code
       NavCategories = await categoryService.GetCategories();
        NavCategoryPages = await categoryPageService.GetCategoryPages();
        //not required
        await Task.Delay(5000);
```

and then in your main component you call the following code for add/edit:

```
            GetCategories();
//if a category has succesfully been edited, it calls the same method which also gets called in the "OnInitializedAsync()"
            await GetCategoriesNav();
```

So which list are you expecting the second calls to update?  The lists in `NavCategoriesComponent` are a totaly separate.  Calling GetCategories() after editing doesn't update the list in `NavCategoriesComponent`.  That only happens when you reload the page.  `OnInitializedAsync` as the name suggests only gets run once.

If that's your basic scenario then:

1. Your `List<Category` and `List<CategoryPage>` lists need to live in `CategoryService`.  Only one version of the truth now.
2. Call `await categoryService.GetCategories()` to get that list when you need it populated.
3. Use the lists directly in `NavCategoriesComponent`.
4. Add an `event` say `RecordListChanged` to `CategoryService`.
5. Register an event handler for that event in `NavCategoriesComponent` and call `StateHasChaged` on that event.
6. Whenever you "Create/Update/Delete" from your modal dialogs, update the `CategoryService` lists and trigger the `RecordListChanged` event.

You should never manually call `OnInitializedAsync`, and you should rarely need to call `StateHasChanged`.

This Github Repo contains a solution that demos the above principles in the good old Blazor WeatherReport app - [Blazr.Demo.DBNotification](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.DBNotification)

Comment: I will try this. I've done roughly the same before, but exactly like this.

Comment: After some struggling, I figured it out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I was reading a lot why my component was not rendering after getting data updated from signalR, so, everywhere they say call StateHasChanged() but It was not working, Thanks to Brian Parker and Curtis's answer above I found what worked for me: call StateHasChanged with InvokeAsync as below:

```
InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)
```

Look at this file line 32 where this is being called that way:
[FetchData.razor](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.DBNotification/blob/master/Blazr.Demo.DBNotification/UI/Pages/FetchData.razor)

Answer (score 0):

An await enable the effects of StatehasChanged(). So change the order.

```
//await Task.Delay(5000);
StateHasChanged();
await Task.Delay(5000);
```